# Group by a column and build a single result row based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to group rows by `account`.

If there's only one row in a group, select it.

If there are multiple rows per group, select columns of the row with `order_number` equal to 4 but set `order_number` to 1.

---

`myTable` data:

```
 account   order_number status    state
  1111           4        ok      full
  2256           4        ok      full
  3344           1        NULL    NULL
  1111           1        NULL    NULL
  8743           4        ok      full
  2256           1        NULL    NULL
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
select 
  account, 
  order_number, 
  status, 
  state, 
  case
    when order_number = '1' then 'pass'
    when order_number = '4' then 'fail'
  end as ' TEST RESULTS '
from myTable
```

This is the result I'm trying to achieve:

```
 account   order_number status    state
  1111           1        ok      full 
  2256           1        ok      full
  3344           1        NULL    NULL
  8743           4        ok      full
```

Comment: I don't understand the required logic here either. Also, why are you storing `order_number` as a `varchar` when it's clearly numerical?

Comment: It can be numerical, its here to try to illustrate the question only.

Comment: Is there any possibility for more than two rows for any account? And please also mention if order_number is always 1 or 4 ?

Answer (score 3):

here is simplest way & probably most performant solution:

```
select accounts
       ,case when cnt > 1 then 1 else order_number end order_number
       ,status,state  
from (
   select * 
      , row_number() over (partition by account order by case when order_number = 4 then 1 else 0 end desc) rn 
      , count(*) over (partition by account) cnt  
) t 
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Good solution, +1. Just a question: why did you order by `case when order_number = 4 then 1 else 0 end` in the window function? Isn't it `order by order_number desc` enough instead of using the `case`?

Comment: Because I imagined order_number can be more than 4 , but if 4 is biggest number possible , you can change it to be just order by order_number

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

Create dummy table for testing

```
[Create table test1(accounts varchar(10), order_number int, status varchar(10),state varchar(10))
  insert into test1 values('1111',4,'ok','full')
  insert into test1 values( '2256'  ,         4  ,      'ok'  ,    'full')
  insert into test1 values('3344' ,          1  ,      NULL  ,  NULL)
  insert into test1 values('1111' ,          1  ,      NULL  ,  NULL)
  insert into test1 values('8743' ,          4  ,      'ok'  ,    'full')
  insert into test1 values('2256'  ,         1  ,      NULL  ,  NULL)][1]
```

Query, no hard coded values

```
Select accounts,
order_number,
status,
state 
from (
        select row_number() over(partition by t1.accounts order by t1.order_number desc) rnum, 
        t1.accounts,
        isnull(t2.order_number,t1.order_number) order_number ,
        t1.status,
        t1.state
        from test1 t1
        left join (select * from test1 where order_number=1) t2 on t1.accounts = t2.accounts and t1.order_number <> t2.order_number
    ) a
where rnum = 1
```

Result set

```
accounts   order_number status     state
---------- ------------ ---------- ----------
1111       1            ok         full
2256       1            ok         full
3344       1            NULL       NULL
8743       4            ok         full
```

**UPDATE: Adding Test Result Column**

```
Select accounts,
order_number,
status,
state,
[TEST RESULTS]
from (
        select row_number() over(partition by t1.accounts order by t1.order_number desc) rnum, 
        t1.accounts,
        isnull(t2.order_number,t1.order_number) order_number ,
        t1.status,
        t1.state,
        case
        when isnull(t2.order_number,t1.order_number) = '1' then 'pass'
        when isnull(t2.order_number,t1.order_number) = '4' then 'fail'
        end as 'TEST RESULTS'
        from test1 t1
        left join (select * from test1 where order_number=1) t2 on t1.accounts = t2.accounts and t1.order_number <> t2.order_number
    ) a
where rnum = 1
```

Comment: Interesting approach, can the test case for "fail" and "pass" be integrated to this method?

Comment: What would be the condition for "pass" and "fail" ? If you want to add another column which will have value "pass" if the values of status and state is replaced, as in for account 1111 and 2256 in your case, the. Yes it can be done.

Comment: No, I don't need to add another column, I need to analyze the values and give a value as a result based on that and do what you showed in your example. Thats why I used the case statements in my question.Thanks!

Comment: @Andre, here you go. Edited my answer to include Test Result column.

Answer (score 1):

Just another option using `WITH TIES` in concert with the window functions `min() over()` and `row_number() over()`

**Example**

```
Select top 1 with ties 
       account
      ,order_number = min(order_number) over(partition by account)
      ,status
      ,state
 From  myTable
 Order By row_number() over (partition by account order by order_number desc)
```

**Results**

```
account order_number    status  state
1111    1               ok      full
2256    1               ok      full
3344    1               NULL    NULL
8743    4               ok      full
```

Answer (score 0):

I only have Access to work with. Output accomplished with:

Query1:

```
SELECT Q1.account, Q1.order_number, Q2.status, Q2.state
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT account, order_number FROM myTable WHERE order_number = 1)  AS Q1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT account, status, state FROM myTable WHERE order_number=4) AS Q2 
ON Q1.account = q2.account;
```

Query2:

```
SELECT account, order_number, status, state FROM Query1
UNION SELECT account, order_number, status, state FROM myTable WHERE NOT account IN(SELECT account FROM Query1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This query has the desired result, but I have doubts about the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` part, because I don't know what is the meaning of `order_number` and, if your real problem is more complex than your question, it may become complicated.

Just changed `ok` to `1` and `full` to `1`

```
SELECT  [T1].[account], [T1].[order_number], COALESCE([T2].[status], [T1].[status]) AS [status], COALESCE([T2].[state], [T1].[state]) AS [state]
FROM    [dbo].[myTable]         [T1]
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[myTable]   [T2]
        ON [T2].[account] = [T1].[account]
        AND [T2].[order_number] = 4
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT  1
    FROM    [dbo].[myTable] [T3]
    WHERE [T3].[account] = [T1].[account]
        AND [T1].[order_number] = 4
        AND [T3].[order_number] = 1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If order_number is always 1 and 4 then below could be the most optimized solution for your problem. Here first I have put a account wise sequence number for all rows starting from 1  in descending order of order_number. So If there is one row for any account number then it 's sequence number (rn) will be 1 and if there are more than one rows then row with order_number 4 will have the sequence number (rn) 1.

So we got our row to select. And to replace order_number 4 with 1 if it's not the only row we calculated row count for each account as column cnt. If cnt>1 and order_number is 4 then we replaced order_number with 1 using `case when`.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table myTable(account   int, order_number int, status varchar(10), state varchar(10));
 insert into myTable values(1111,           4,        'ok',      'full');
 insert into myTable values(2256,           4,        'ok',      'full');
 insert into myTable values(3344,           1,        NULL,    NULL);
 insert into myTable values(1111,           1,        NULL,    NULL);
 insert into myTable values(8743,           4,        'ok',      'full');
 insert into myTable values(2256,           1,        NULL,    NULL);
```

Query:

```
 with cte as 
 (
   select account,order_number,status,state,row_number()over(partition by account order by order_number desc)rn,
   count(order_number)over(partition by account )cnt
   from mytable
 )select account,(case when order_number=4 and cnt>1 then 1 else order_number end) order_number,status,state 
 from cte where rn=1
```

Output:

| account | order_number | status | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 1 | ok | full |
| 2256 | 1 | ok | full |
| 3344 | 1 | *null* | *null* |
| 8743 | 4 | ok | full |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fdaca2bb66e59b8d3ed092a643ea8ada)*

Comment: @Andre please let me know your feedbac.

Comment: I don't see many differences from the one proposed by @eshirvana honestly. In terms of execution plan, I expect them to be the same.

Comment: That's correct. But out of curiosity when I have tried both query with 24024006 rows in the table mine took 49% time.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how. You will have my +1 when you prove it with the execution plan and an explanation :)

Comment: Will try to find one.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the above result by using Aggregate Function Like `MIN & MAX`

```
DECLARE  @myTable TABLE (account   int, order_number int, status varchar(10), state varchar(10)) 
 INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES(1111,           4,        'ok',      'full');
 INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES(2256,           4,        'ok',      'full');
 INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES(3344,           1,        NULL,    NULL);
 INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES(1111,           1,        NULL,    NULL);
 INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES(8743,           4,        'ok',      'full');
 INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES(2256,           1,        NULL,    NULL);
```

Query:

```
SELECT  account,MIN(order_number) order_number,MAX(status) status,MAX(State) State
FROM @myTable
GROUP BY account
```